# SWIFT: Replace double backslash with single backslash in a string

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode

I have a string that has the value of "\\u{abc}" and I want to change it to "\u{abc}"

My code is as it follows

```
str = "\\u{abc}"
let newstr = str.remove(at: str.startIndex)
print(newstr)
```

The output is: u{abc}

How can I remove just the first one ?

I also tried using replacing occurrences and dropfirst
Does anyone know how to fix this

Thanks for your time

Comment: The actual output of `print(newstr)` is a single backslash character: `str.remove()` returns the removed character, not the remaining string.

Answer (score 2):

i am editing the answer sorry i made huge mistake, here is the correction

```
var str = "\\u{abc}"

print(str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: #"\"#))

ouput : \u{abc}
```

Comment: first that I saw in your answer is your original string got extra \

Comment: and your output is really: \઼
why?

Comment: @IlyaMuradymov please now check sorry i made a mistake out of rush maybe

Comment: thx man ! The code itself works, the problem is when i atribute it to a label , the double backslash comes back,

Answer (score 0):

Let's go

if you try to just

```
print("\u")
```

Xcode will warn you: **Expected hexadecimal code in braces after unicode escape.**

so, Xcode expecting some hexadecimal value, and this is where the conflict begins

your solution, specifically with \U is:

```
let newstr = "\\" + str.dropFirst()
```

Full is:

```
var str = "\\u{abc}"
let newstr = "\\" + str.dropFirst()
print(newstr)
```